# autocomplete in bash script

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am trying to autocomplete a folder name in a bash script. If I enter a complete folder name everything works, but I don't know how to autocomplete the name. Any ideas?

```
repo() {
 cd ~/Desktop/_REPOS/$1
}
```

I tried reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791642/find-based-filename-autocomplete-in-bash-script) for ideas, but got lost quickly because I am still fairly new to bash.

GOAL (with the repo function above included in my bashrc):

```
>ls ~/Desktop/_REPOS/
folder1
hellofolder
stackstuff

>repo sta[TAB] fills in as: repo stackstuff
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually you can borrow quite a bit of code from [geirha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12025812/1601806):

```
# this is a custom function that provides matches for the bash autocompletion
_repo_complete() {
    local file
    # iterate all files in a directory that start with our search string
    for file in ~/Desktop/_REPOS/"$2"*; do
        # If the glob doesn't match, we'll get the glob itself, so make sure
        # we have an existing file. This check also skips entries
        # that are not a directory
        [[ -d $file ]] || continue

        # add the file without the ~/Desktop/_REPOS/ prefix to the list of 
        # autocomplete suggestions
        COMPREPLY+=( $(basename "$file") )
    done
}

# this line registers our custom autocompletion function to be invoked 
# when completing arguments to the repo command
complete -F _repo_complete repo
```

The `for` loop iterates all files in a directory that start with the string given as second argument to the `_repo_complete` function (this is the string to be autocompleted).

Add the code to your `.bashrc` and it should work!

Comment: If I wanted to remove the `repo()` function and put the code inside `_repo_complete` (to get only one function), how would I do it?

Comment: can I just change the final line to `complete -F _repo_complete`?

Comment: I do not think that is practical, since the `_repo_complete` function gets invoked every time the autocomplete is attempted. You could try to hack around this by checking if there is already a valid directory name, but I think that mess is not worth saving one function.

Comment: You probably don't need to add it to `.bashrc`. As per [this FAQ](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/README.md), user completion scripts are sourced from `~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/`; this directory can be created by the user. At least on Ubuntu, system completion scripts are generally stored in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`.

Answer (score 8):

I see two options to get what you want, i.e., path autocompletion for a custom `cd` command, if I understand correctly.

1. You can add the parent directory, `~/Desktop/_REPOS`, to your `CDPATH` environment variable:

   ```
   CDPATH="$CDPATH":"$HOME"/Desktop/_REPOS
   ```

   Now, from any directory, you can type `cd` <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, and in addition to the subdirectories of your current directory, all the directories in `~/Desktop/_REPOS` will show up. (Which is also the drawback of this method: more clutter.)
2. You can add a completion function to your `.bashrc`. The way you've started, you want the basenames of all the directories in `~/Desktop/_REPOS`. To get autocompletion for directories, we can use the `compgen -d` builtin:

   ```
   $ compgen -d "$HOME"/Desktop/_REPOS/
   /home/me/Desktop/_REPOS/folder1
   /home/me/Desktop/_REPOS/folder2
   /home/me/Desktop/_REPOS/stackstuff
   /home/me/Desktop/_REPOS/hellofolder
   ```

   This returns the names of all subdirectories. It reduces to fewer candidates when the path is more specific:

   ```
   $ compgen -d "$HOME"/Desktop/_REPOS/f
   /home/me/Desktop/_REPOS/folder1
   /home/me/Desktop/_REPOS/folder2
   ```

   To remove everything but the basenames, we use shell parameter expansion, like this:

   ```
   $ arr=(/path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2)
   $ echo "${arr[@]##*/}"
   dir1 dir2
   ```

   `##*/` in the parameter expansion removes the longest possible match of `*/` from each element of `arr`, i.e., leaves only what's after the last forward slash – exactly what we want.

   Now we put this together and into a function:

   ```
   _comp_repo () {
       # Get list of directories
       # $2 is the word being completed
       COMPREPLY=($(compgen -d "$HOME"/Desktop/_REPOS/"$2"))

       # Reduce to basenames
       COMPREPLY=("${COMPREPLY[@]##*/}")
   }
   ```

   This goes into your `.bashrc`, together with the instruction to use it for autocompletion with `repo`:

   ```
   complete -F _comp_repo repo
   ```

   Notice that your `repo` function should quote the `$1` argument to make sure it handles directory names with special characters (spaces, tabs...) properly:

   ```
   repo () {
       cd ~/Desktop/_REPOS/"$1"
   }
   ```

The number of times you have hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> depends on [readline settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax) such as `show-all-if-ambiguous`.

---

**References**

- Bash manual

  - [`CDPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-cd)
  - [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
  - [The `compgen` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-compgen)
  - [The `complete` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-complete)

Comment: You probably don't need to add it to `.bashrc`. As per [this FAQ](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/README.md), user completion scripts are sourced from `~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/`; this directory can be created by the user. At least on Ubuntu, system completion scripts are generally stored in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`.

Comment: @Acumenus You're right - one caveat: this requires bash-completion to be installed. Adding the completion function to `~/.bashrc` guarantees that it works even without bash-completion installed. The completions specified in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` and `$XGD_DATA_HOME/bash-completion/completions` have the big advantage that they are loaded dynamically the first time they're required; a disadvantage is that it requires a new-ish version of bash-completion, and the system path isn't the same everywhere (macOS: `/usr/local/opt/bash-completion@2/share/bash-completion/completions`).

Comment: Bash-completion also understands a few fallback locations: all files in `/etc/bash_completion.d` (this is where most homebrew packages stick their completions), and `~/.bash_completion`, both of which are sourced in any case rather than loaded dynamically, but still keep `~/.bashrc` a bit more clutter-free.

Comment: And lastly, if you know that bash-completion is installed, you can take advantage of its helper functions such as `_init_completion`, which are very robust argument parsers and used in all the completions provided by bash-completion itself - again, requiring that it is installed.

Comment: I expect most modern Linux distros to have bash-completion installed.

Comment: @Acumenus Likely, but you immediately get an explosion of complexity to cover all the cases. The answer is guaranteed to work on its own.

Comment: If we want answers that are guaranteed to work on their own, it's easier to ask someone to install bash-completion in the rare case that it's missing, rather than to ignore the 90% who already have it. Adding a code block to a preexisting file is actually a hard problem from an idempotence p.o.v., whereas creating a new file meant just for this is easily idempotent.